# How to run integration tests with maven failsafe when pom.xml has <skipITs>true</skipITs>

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've set true in pom.xml but I want to be able to run tests when I wish to run them. I've tried `mvn -Prun-its clean verify` and `mvn verify -DskipITs=false` but they're not working, the tests are skipped still.

The added plugin in the pom.xml is as follows:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-jupiter-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

In the output of `mvn verify -DskipITs=false` I can see the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:verify (default) @ redis-service-integration-tests ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

Comment: could you please provide a pom.xml to see what exactly is your problem, along w/ generated output if possible. Thanks.

Comment: if you remove skipITs in POM, it will execute the tests, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I suggest to take a look into https://youtu.be/IVwbrhYCLpc Also do not use manually defined surefire-junit47 providers... better leave it to the dependencies... and better use most recent versions of surefire/failsafe plugins versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the plugin configuration to be like this:

```
  <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
```

Explanation:
to make the property mechanism work, you should use the project properties `<properties>` to set the skipITs instead of the plugin configuration, otherwise it can't be easily overridden from outside.

Comment: But then if nothing is provided in the skipITs argument , it will error out?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly, but if empty, it should be interpreted as false, try..

Comment: Okay, just checked if nothing is provided then it runs the tests. I want the default behaviour to not run tests and it should run only when i want it to. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Just saw updated answer, will check with properties